# Why isn't \def working?

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I just learned about the "amsthm" package and I am trying to learn how to use it. As I understand it this package already has some predefined environments such as "def", but I can make new environments by doing

```
\newtheorem{What I use to summon the environment}{Name of the environment}
```

Now I have a piece of LaTex that works fine if I use

```
\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Definition}
```

but it does not work if I use the standard predefined "def". Here it is

```
\begin{def}

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ be a 
function. We say that $f$ is differentiable at $z \in G$ if

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}$$

exists. If it exists, we denote this limit as $f'(z)$.

\end{def}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.49 ...n subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f: G \to
                                               \mathbb{C}$ be a function...
```

Comment: `\def` is a tex primitive, intended for defining commands.  Latex `\newcommand` is built on `\def`, so any attempt to reuse or redefine `\def` is "by definition" destined to fail.  This doesn't explain why you got the error message you show, but should be fair warning that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ahh thanks. So is it standard then to just stick to making your own environment with \newtheorem like I did?

Comment: `\newtheorem` (along with `\theoremsyle` and, if needed, `\newtheoremstyle`) is the intended use of `amsthm`.  I recommend reading the user guide -- `texdoc amsthdoc`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks!

Comment: unrelated but do not use `$$` in latex, and never have a blank line before a math display. Or a blank line after it if (as here) the following text is not anew paragraph.

Comment: To create commands and environments with odd arrangements of optional arguments, you can use the xparse package.  You can do it with \def but it is ugly.  You wind up defining  a bunch of commands with only one argument (or so) each, and using `\ifnextchar[\fooa\foob` a lot.